# Community Engine v. Social Stream?

Tags: social-networking, communityengine, social-stream

Newb here learning rails... any advice/comparison of community engine v. social stream?  I'll be writing a dating site, so especially if either lends themselves to that development I'd appreciate the advice.

Comment: Did you try them out? Can you answer this question yourself now?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried CommunityEngine in the old days. Currently to use it with rails3, you will have to use a specific branch mainly updated by the community to make it stable. i'm not sure if that rails3 branch is production ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know community engine, but have been looking at social stream and it looks very well put together.

Answer (score 0):

We upgraded social stream to a mobile platform by exposing api end points - it took a couple of months. We built separate controllers for each call rather than modifying the core classes. The platform is now flexible enough to cater for any use case and we can hook in to updates on the trunk. It's really well thought architecture and has had iterations of refactoring. (I think the webviews / javascript is a bit of a mess though)

I suggest you have a look at this - it took my tech lead a couple of weeks to be comfortable with this.
https://github.com/ging/social_stream/wiki/Social-Stream-Base-database-schema

WRT communityengine - I abandoned this over 4 years ago. 
https://github.com/jdp-global/communityengine/commit/31f9b267706157a63bfc103a290bd6e3d874066a

Any platform you choose needs to have a focus on APIs / web services.